# Cambiar columna de una tabla para que sea AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con un Id y un nombre. Estoy tratando de poblarla de la siguiente forma:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
load data infile'C:LarutademiCSV.csv'
into table t1
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
IGNORE 1 lines
(idt1, nombreT1)
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Pero son 100 archivos de 1'000.000 de registros y cada archivo tiene definido el id de 1 a 1'000.000 por lo que al insertarlo, me marca error de llaves duplicadas. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar desde la sentencia que el campo id sea auto_increment?

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es declarar el campo `AUTO_INCREMENT` en el `CREATE TABLE`. Luego, insertas todas las columnas que quieras del archivo, menos esa que tiene el campo que es auto_increment. El manejador se encargará de ir creando ese campo de forma secuencial. O sea, haces el insert así más o menos: `load data infile'C:LarutademiCSV.csv' into table t1 fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 lines (nombreT1)`. Aquí se supone que en el csv hay una columna llamada `nombreT1`.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que primero crees la tabla con el campo idT1 como AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableT1` (
   `idT1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nombreT1` varchar(30),
   PRIMARY KEY (`idT1 `)
);
```

o, si ya la tienes creada, la actualices:

```
ALTER TABLE `tableT1` ADD `idT1` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Y luego cargues el archivo tu CSV:

```
LOAD DATA
  INFILE `C:LarutademiCSV.csv`
  INTO TABLE tableT1
  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY `","`  
  LINES TERMINATED BY `\r\n` ;
```